# How do I programmatically close the Immersive Reader?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, immersive-reader

I would like to be able to close the Immersive Reader in code, without the need for user intervention. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ImmersiveReader.close()` function to close the Immersive Reader. The documentation is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/immersive-reader/reference#close).